# How to SELECT from SHOW TABLE STATUS results

Tags: mysql, select

I'd like to limit the rows and columns that come back from the

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS
```

command in MySQL 5.1.  Is there a way to get this same information through a `SELECT` statement so I can manipulate the results in a normal way?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This has more columns than SHOW TABLE STATUS; but does the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = DATABASE();
```

UPDATE 2011-06-07 19:02

```
SELECT table_name,Engine,Version,Row_format,table_rows,Avg_row_length,
Data_length,Max_data_length,Index_length,Data_free,Auto_increment,
Create_time,Update_time,Check_time,table_collation,Checksum,
Create_options,table_comment FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = DATABASE();
```

These queries work if you set the current database.

You can also hard code the specific database:

```
SELECT table_name,Engine,Version,Row_format,table_rows,Avg_row_length,
Data_length,Max_data_length,Index_length,Data_free,Auto_increment,
Create_time,Update_time,Check_time,table_collation,Checksum,
Create_options,table_comment FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'mysql';
```

Answer (score 12):

```
show table status like 'table1';
```

You can't manipulate the columns this way, but it is easier to select just the tables you want and get the normal `SHOW TABLE STATUS` output.

Comment: Which limits the rows but not the columns, right?

Comment: Correct. You can't manipulate the columns this way, but it is easier to select just the tables you want and get the normal SHOW TABLE STATUS output.

Answer (score 4):

You can use WHERE or LIKE as for SELECT:

```
show table status where name='name';
```

Answer (score 2):

`show table status` can be used without selecting current database:

```
show table status from DbName where name='TableName';
```

See [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-table-status.html):

> ```
> SHOW TABLE STATUS
>     [{FROM | IN} db_name]
>     [LIKE 'pattern' | WHERE expr]
> ```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this query to display all Information Schema.

SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = DATABASE();

or the shorthand:

SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'tableName'

Comment: I don't see anything in this answer that hasn't been already posted in other answers.